# how to get root folder URL for image uploads in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i am using image in page in word press.when i upload the image from my system that get local host id.if i migrate to server that URL was missing.
so i want to get dynamic root URL in word press to apply in image src.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`bloginfo( 'template_url' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) when adding images to your theme:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/images/your-image.png" />
```